# Displaying contents of HTML from full Readability Parser API

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, readability

I'm using the full **Readability API Parser**, but a bit of a newcomer.  Once I get the response back, I get the raw contents of the HTML.

[image]

**My questions are**:

- Is it best to create a separate class to style this?
- Should I use a UIWebview to display that data once styled?
- Or can I just style it in the same viewDidLoad that I'm grabbing the
  contents?

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=%@/&token=xxxx", stringWeb]];`

Thanks for the help, I can post any code necessary thats needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are going to reuse the styling in other places in your project, it would be great to create a separate class so that you can avoid duplication of code for the same style. Otherwise you can just use style it in the same viewDidLoad, provided you have got the content from the Readability API.

You can certainly use UIWebView to display the data because it contains HTML. If you want to make it does not look like a web view, you can tweak it to remove the shadows on the top and the bottom of the web view when the web view bounces.

Or you can try to use something like DTCoreText: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I won't be using the styling in other places, so I'll probably style it in the `viewDidLoad` then.  Can you give me some example of what sort of code I would use to style what I already have from my code I posted?  If not thats ok, but like I said earlier, I'm newer to this part.  Thanks!

Comment: For example, if I just wanted to display the `author` and `body`?

Comment: @Reez you will need to parse the JSON and take the author and body  values accordingly. Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html or other iOS JSON parsing tutorials :)